# How can I read line after line from big String?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

Consider I have some big String in the following structure:

```
parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4+"\0"
```

*Where parameter is sequence of some chars in a generally unknown length.

Now consider my big String is holding 4 lines of data, for example:

```
parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4+"\0"
parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4+"\0"
parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4+"\0"
parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4+"\0"
```

How can I read the first line and then read the second line and so on?
I know that I can use `Substring` method to get the first line every time easily, however
how can I use `Substring`(or other methods) to get the next 3 lines of the big string, in order to extract the first line again (which represent the second line of the original big string in practice).
I know that all I need is the index of the last "\0" (line 4) and I already have the index of current line "\0".

Should I just use `lastIndexOf("\0")`?
If you have any other ideas or even criticism about this way of working, I'll be more than glad to hear about.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with a `"\0"` argument. You will then get an array of strings (`String[]`) which you can then do whatever you wish with :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the StringReader wrapped into a BufferedReader, something like:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("my multiline text..."));
String l = null;
while ((l=r.readLine)!=null) {
 ....
 // each line in "l"
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps,

```
inputString.split("\0");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression to separate the string. In case you want all words in one string array you can just use /s (whitespace) as a separator pattern.

You can find information here http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html